# How to do division from select statements in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, select

I am trying to create a select statement that can return a table of 1 column.
Basically, I am looping through all the records of `NewHire`, and then using its id, to select stuff from another table. I then do a count to get the number of rows, and then divide to get a percentage value, and then I want to insert it to this temp table `t`. Then select `t`. But this isn't working. I am getting syntax errors.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
declare @t table (Percentage int)
DECLARE @acc INT 
SET @acc = 1
DECLARE @max INT 
select @max = max(HireID) from NewHire
WHILE (@acc <= @max)
BEGIN
  IF (@acc in (select HireID from NewHire))
  BEGIN
    insert into @t  
      (select COUNT(*) from Hire_Response WHERE HireID = @acc) /
      (select COUNT(*) from Hire_Response WHERE HireID = @acc 
       AND (HireResponse = 0 OR HireResponse = 1))
  END
  set @acc = @acc + 1
END
select * from @t
```

Comment: And the errors are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an additional `select` just after your `insert`.

```
declare @t table (Percentage int)
DECLARE @acc INT 
SET @acc = 1
DECLARE @max INT 
select @max = max(HireID) from NewHire
WHILE (@acc <= @max)
    BEGIN
        IF (@acc in (select HireID from NewHire))
            BEGIN try
                insert into @t  
                select
                    (select COUNT(*) from Hire_Response WHERE HireID = @acc) /
                    (select COUNT(*) from Hire_Response WHERE HireID = @acc AND (HireResponse = 0 OR HireResponse = 1))
            END try
            begin catch
                insert into @t 
                select 0
            end catch
        set @acc = @acc + 1
    END
select * from @t
```

There is more than one way to do this though, but the above is your quickest fix to the provided query

Comment: That worked, but now for a lot of them I get divide by zero errors, is there a way so that, you can do a check if its a 0/0, and if so, just force the result to be a 0?

Comment: You can use a `TRY CATCH`. I have updated the example above

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this can be done with a single SQL statement, actually, something like this:

```
select case when n2 = 0 then 0 else n1/n2 from (
 select 
  h.hireId, 
  count(*) as n1, 
  sum(case when r.hireResponse in (0,1) then 1 else 0 end) as n2
  from
   NewHire h, Hire_Response r
  where
   h.hireId = r.hireId
  group by
   h.hireId
)
```

I don't have a SQL Server instance handy to test it, but it's basic SQL so I expect it to be supported.